# untag a product / remove a product-tag relationship

Tags: magento-1.8, tags

How to remove a tag/product relationship programmatically?

I've tried:

```
$tag_obj    = $tagModel->loadByName($tag);
$tagId      = $tag_obj->getTagId();
$customerId = $tag_obj->getCustomerId();

$relationModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');

$relationModel->loadByTagCustomer($productId, $tagId, $customerId, $store['id'])->deactivate();
```

But it doesn't seem to do much, much less untag anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order  *to delete a customer from tag*,use [aggregate()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Tag.php#L290) function after calling  *`deactivate()`*.

```
   $relationModel  = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');
    $relationModel ->loadByTagCustomer($productId, $tagId, $customerId);
    if($relationModel->getTagId()):
         $tagId=$relationModel->getTagId();
        try {
            $relationModel ->deactivate();
            $tag = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->load($tagId)->aggregate();
            // Mage::helper('tag')->__('The tag has been deleted.');

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::helper('tag')->__('Unable to remove tag. Please, try again later.');
        }


    endif;
```

**Also if you want to detete tag then use**

```
$tag->delete()
```

Comment: I'll try it out. I'm interested in removing the relationship, not the tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Deactive Relation**

```
 $tagRelation  = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');
 $tagRelation ->loadByTagCustomer($productId, $tagId, $customerId, $storeId);
 $tagRelation->deactivate();
```

**Delete Relation**

```
$tagRelation  = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');
$tagRelation ->loadByTagCustomer($productId, $tagId, $customerId, $storeId);
if($tagRelation->getId()) {
    $tagRelation->delete()
}
```

Comment: But that will delete the tag, wouldn't it? I don't want to delete the tag (it might me be used by a different product), I want to remove the relationship... And thanks for the Add part, I have that already under control. :)

Comment: have you tag id or product id?

Comment: Yes, I have the tag Id, the product Id, and the Customer Id. (And the store Id)

Comment: updated ans. Pls check now